# Concurrent bamboo builds on different remote agents

Tags: build, bamboo

I have 2 remote agents for the build, what is the entire process to fire a same build using bamboo,concurrently on those two different agents.

Comment: A plan can only be run by only one agent at a time. You probably need to create two plans with different requirements to build the same code using two remote agents (for compability testing). Also, take a look at Team City matrix build.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, change your build requirement variable so that those two agents can both build this plan.
2. Then change the max concurrent build variable to >= 2.
3. Then I think you can trigger the same plan twice, and see they're running on two agents.

But this is not very recommended since there's a slight chance the agents will shuffle jobs.
Build 1 has 3 stages which ran first on agent #1, Build 2 ran after on agent #2, by the time Build 2 is in stage 3, it might be running on agent#1 or agent#2 depending on whether the agent is idle.